# Neo4j use result of MATCH as parameter to CALL

Tags: neo4j

I would like to look up data in my Neo4j graph and then pass the results to a method defined in a plugin. I can't figure out the correct syntax.

I would expect something like:

```
MATCH (a)-[:LIKES]->(b) CALL myworld.analyze(a)
```

which would call my user-defined method and do appropriate processing, returning the Stream that is generated by my method.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: alternative syntax: `CALL myworld.analyze(MATCH (a)-[:LIKES]->(b) return a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just have to return sth from the procedure:

```
MATCH (a)-[:LIKES]->(b) 
CALL myworld.analyze(a) YIELD result
RETURN result
```